# Store value in variable from an if statement within a switch statement case

Tags: javascript, angularjs, if-statement, switch-statement

I want to have a variable keep track of results from an `if` statement in every case of a switch statement. The problem is every time my case uses the initial value of the variable - 0, and not value given by the previous case, so I always get `myNum = 1`. I want to know what is a common solution to this problem.

I also tried this with an array `var myArray = [false,false,false,false];` where case 1 changes `myArray[0] = true`, when `if` statement in case 2 returns `true` it changes `myArray[1] = true`, however the entire array is now `[false,true,false,false]`, i.e. the changes from case 1 are not saved in the variable and it is instead using the initial variable value.

Both cases are the same if I log value to console outside of the switch statement.

```
$scope.clickItem = function(result){
var myNum = 0;
function addNum() {
  myNum++;
};

switch(currentString) {
    case string1:
    if($scope.img1 === result){
         addNum();
         console.log('myNum is ' + myNum); // <- It's 1
         $scope.currentString = $scope.val2;
     }
     else{
         console.log("Wrong..");
     }
    break;

    case $scope.val2:
    if($scope.img2 === result){
        addNum();
        console.log('myNum is ' + myNum); // <- It's 1 again, when it should be 2.
        $scope.currentString = $scope.val3;
     }
     else{
         console.log("Wrong..");
     }
    break;

    case $scope.val3:
    if($scope.img3 === result){
         addNum();
         $scope.currentString = $scope.val4;
     }
     else{
    console.log("Wrong..");
}
break;
}
...etc
```

Comment: I am not a big fan of, but you could make your variable global so it will be initialized on the start of the app and then incremented every time it is required.

Comment: As shown, `myNum` would be global, so it should retain its value, but if it's a local variable inside a function that you haven't shown then it would be reset each time the function it's inside is run - you could fix that by declaring `myNum` at the same scope level as the function that contains the above code. Please [edit] your question to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: As you didn't provide the full code, I just guess, you have to set the *myNum* out of the loop. Now, each run you reset the variable. And move the function *addNum()* outside the loop too.

Comment: Instead of using a global, I suggest you try looking at angular services. Essentially they are singletons that you can inject into your controllers

Answer (score 0):

Your `myNum` variable is set to 0 every time you call the `clickItem` function. It can not get over 1.

What you should do is set a global variable in your `$scope` this way:

```
$scope.myNum = 0;
$scope.clickItem = function(result){
    function addNum() {
        $scope.myNum++;
    };
    ...
};
```

Don't forget to change how you log the result:

```
console.log("myNum is" + $scope.myNum);
```